# How to calculate coefficients of polynomial using Lagrange interpolation

Tags: javascript, polynomial-math

I need to calculate coefficients of polynomial using Lagrange [interpolation polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), as my homework, I decide to do this in Javascript.

here is definition of Lagrange polynomial (L(x))

[image]

Lagrange basis polynomials are defined as follows

[image]

Calculate y value for specific X (W(x) function) is simple but I need to calculate coefficients of polynomial (array of [a0, a1, ..., an]) I need to do this to n<=10 but it will be nice to have arbitrary n, then I can put that function into horner function and draw that polynomial.

[image]

I have function that calculate denominator in first equation

```
function denominator(i, points) {
   var result = 1;
   var x_i = points[i].x;
   for (var j=points.length; j--;) {
      if (i != j) {
        result *= x_i - points[j].x;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

and function that return y using horner method (I also have drawing function using canvas)

```
function horner(array, x_scale, y_scale) {
   function recur(x, i, array) {
      if (i == 0) {
         return x*array[0];
      } else {
         return array[i] + x*recur(x, --i, array);
      }
   }
   return function(x) {
      return recur(x*x_scale, array.length-1, array)*y_scale;
   };
}
```

anybody know algorithm to do this, or idea how to calculate those coefficients

Comment: Don't use Wikipedia -- http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/LagrangePolynomial.html

Comment: @JamesSumners - Wikipedia has some significant benefits, for example pages are far less likely to disappear and end as 404 like your link.

Comment: Well that 404 is surprising. It's a fairly significant algebra concept. PlanetMath in almost every case has a more thorough explanation, and did when I added the link.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180110121005/http://planetmath.org:80/lagrangeinterpolationformula <== archive link to get around the 404 in my previous comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can do it the naive way. Represent a polynomial by the array of its coefficients, the array

```
[a_0,a_1,...,a_n]
```

corresponding to `a_0 + a_1*X + ... + a_n*X^n`. I'm no good with JavaScript, so pseudocode will have to do:

```
interpolation_polynomial(i,points)
    coefficients = [1/denominator(i,points)]
    for k = 0 to points.length-1
        if k == i
            next k
        new_coefficients = [0,0,...,0] // length k+2 if k < i, k+1 if k > i
        if k < i
            m = k
        else
            m = k-1
        for j = m downto 0
            new_coefficients[j+1] += coefficients[j]
            new_coefficients[j] -= points[k]*coefficients[j]
        coefficients = new_coefficients
    return coefficients
```

Start with the constant polynomial `1/((x_1-x_0)* ... *(x_i-x_{i-1})*(x_i-x_{i+1})*...*(x_i-x_n))` and multiply with `X - x_k` for all `k != i`. So that gives the coefficients for L<sub>i</sub>, then you just multiply them with y<sub>i</sub> (you could do that by initialising `coefficients` to `y_i/denominator(i,points)` if you pass the y-values as parameters) and add all the coefficients together finally.

```
polynomial = [0,0,...,0] // points.length entries
for i = 0 to points.length-1
    coefficients = interpolation_polynomial(i,points)
    for k = 0 to points.length-1
        polynomial[k] += y[i]*coefficients[k]
```

Calculating each L<sub>i</sub> is O(n²), so the total calculation is O(n³).

**Update:** In your jsFiddle, you had an error in the polynomial multiplication loop in addition to (the now corrected) mistake with the start index I made, it should be

```
for (var j= (k < i) ? (k+1) : k; j--;) {
     new_coefficients[j+1] += coefficients[j];
     new_coefficients[j] -= points[k].x*coefficients[j];
}
```

Since you decrement `j` when testing, it needs to start one higher.

That doesn't produce a correct interpolation yet, but it's at least more sensible than before.

Also, in your `horner` function,

```
function horner(array, x_scale, y_scale) {
   function recur(x, i, array) {
      if (i == 0) {
         return x*array[0];
      } else {
         return array[i] + x*recur(x, --i, array);
      }
   }
   return function(x) {
      return recur(x*x_scale, array.length-1, array)*y_scale;
   };
}
```

you multiply the highest coefficient twice with `x`, it should be

```
if (i == 0) {
    return array[0];
}
```

instead. Still no good result, though.

**Update2:** Final typo fixes, the following works:

```
function horner(array, x_scale, y_scale) {
   function recur(x, i, array) {
      if (i == 0) {
         return array[0];
      } else {
         return array[i] + x*recur(x, --i, array);
      }
   }
   return function(x) {
      return recur(x*x_scale, array.length-1, array)*y_scale;
   };
}

// initialize array
function zeros(n) {
   var array = new Array(n);
   for (var i=n; i--;) {
     array[i] = 0;
   }
   return array;
}

function denominator(i, points) {
   var result = 1;
   var x_i = points[i].x;
   for (var j=points.length; j--;) {
      if (i != j) {
        result *= x_i - points[j].x;
      }
   }
    console.log(result);
   return result;
}

// calculate coefficients for Li polynomial
function interpolation_polynomial(i, points) {
   var coefficients = zeros(points.length);
    // alert("Denominator " + i + ": " + denominator(i,points));
   coefficients[0] = 1/denominator(i,points);
    console.log(coefficients[0]);
    //new Array(points.length);
   /*for (var s=points.length; s--;) {
      coefficients[s] = 1/denominator(i,points);
   }*/
   var new_coefficients;

   for (var k = 0; k<points.length; k++) {
      if (k == i) {
        continue;
      }
      new_coefficients = zeros(points.length);
       for (var j= (k < i) ? k+1 : k; j--;) {
         new_coefficients[j+1] += coefficients[j];
         new_coefficients[j] -= points[k].x*coefficients[j];
      }   
      coefficients = new_coefficients;
   }
   console.log(coefficients);
   return coefficients;
}

// calculate coefficients of polynomial
function Lagrange(points) {
   var polynomial = zeros(points.length);
   var coefficients;
   for (var i=0; i<points.length; ++i) {
     coefficients = interpolation_polynomial(i, points);
     //console.log(coefficients);
     for (var k=0; k<points.length; ++k) {
       // console.log(points[k].y*coefficients[k]);
        polynomial[k] += points[i].y*coefficients[k];
     }
   }
   return polynomial;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it to work in JS, what this line means `coefficients = [1/denominator(i,points)]` create array with one element or create every element to be the same or every element to be different?

Comment: The first one, an array with one element. You could also create a longer array and set all other entries to 0. Looking at your `horner` function, I just notice that you use the arrays as coefficients with `a[0]` corresponding to the highest power's coefficient, while I made it the constant term. If you haven't noticed that, that would lead to completely wrong results. You have to reverse some arrays.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JdwNw/ and only 1 and last polynomial in `interpolation_polynomial` function return some values. I think that I will accept the answer and create another question for this.

Comment: Fiddling around a bit with the fiddle, `denominator(i,points)` tends to return `NaN`. I'm at a loss why, though.

Comment: @daniel-fisher I put `console.log(result)` in denominator function and `console.log(coefficients[0]);` in interpolation_polynomial function and they both return numbers.

Comment: Ah, oops, I changed the generation of `points` and messed that up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9316/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-jcubic)

Comment: Note that this code, even for 2012, does not follow JS conventions so if you're going to use this, remember to rewrite it to proper JS at the same time. Also note that JS changed a _lot_ in the decade between this answer and this comment, and this code does a bunch of things that made sense back in the day, but have since been replaced by newer syntax and/or convention

Answer (score 1):

This code will determine the coefficients starting with the constant term.

```js
const xPoints = [2, 4, 3, 6, 7, 10]; //example coordinates
const yPoints = [2, 5, -2, 0, 2, 8];
const coefficients = xPoints.map((_) => 0);

for (let m = 0; m < xPoints.length; m++) {
  const newCoefficients = xPoints.map((_) => 0);

  if (m > 0) {
    newCoefficients[0] = -xPoints[0] / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[0]);
    newCoefficients[1] = 1 / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[0]);
  } else {
    newCoefficients[0] = -xPoints[1] / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[1]);
    newCoefficients[1] = 1 / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[1]);
  }

  let startIndex = m === 0 ? 2 : 1;

  for (let n = startIndex; n < xPoints.length; n++) {
    if (m === n) continue;

    for (let nc = xPoints.length - 1; nc >= 1; nc--) {
      newCoefficients[nc] =
        newCoefficients[nc] * (-xPoints[n] / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[n])) +
        newCoefficients[nc - 1] / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[n]);
    }

    newCoefficients[0] =
      newCoefficients[0] * (-xPoints[n] / (xPoints[m] - xPoints[n]));
  }

  for (let nc = 0; nc < xPoints.length; nc++)
    coefficients[nc] += yPoints[m] * newCoefficients[nc];
}
```

Comment: Don't use the legacy `var` in 2020, _especially not_ as loop variables. If you have to ask "why not", then that's exactly why: it doesn't work like "normal" variables, it's scoped to the entire function, not to a code block. Use `let` for reassignable variables, and `const` for finals. Never use `var`.

Comment: (Also even with that updated, this code can't run, and was clearly not copied from a working implementation)

Comment: It is taken from a working example and works fine. The indentation of the above code could be fixed to aid readability, but the code works.

Comment: Then look at the code again, because there's brackets missing that cause it to _not_ work right now. That "if" with two statements under it for instance, _won't conditionally run those two statements_, because that's not how `if` without brackets works.

Comment: Are we looking at the same code? The first IF does use brackets as it has two lines it needs to execute. The second (and third) IF doesn't need brackets as it is only needs to execute one line.

Comment: apparently not. The indentation was heavily throwing things off so I've updated it to use proper indentation.

Comment: Nice and fast algorithm! Where does it come from? Does it have a name?

Comment: It's a Lagrange Polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You can find coefficients of Lagrange interpolation polynomial relatively easy if you use a matrix form of Lagrange interpolation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)
", section "Lagrange interpolation". I'm afraid, I don't know JavaScript to provide you with appropriate code, but I worked with Python a little bit, maybe the following can help (sorry for bad codestyle -- I'm mathematician, not programmer)

```py
import numpy as np
# input
x = [0, 2, 4, 5]  # <- x's
y = [2, 5, 7, 7]  # <- y's
# calculating coefficients
M = [[_x**i*(-1)**(i*len(x)) for _x in x] for i in range(len(x))]
C = [np.linalg.det((M+[y]+M)[d:d+len(x)]) for d in range(len(x)+1)]
C = (C / C[0] * (-1)**(len(x)+1) )[1:]
# polynomial lambda-function
poly = lambda _x: sum([C[i] * _x**i for i in range(len(x))])
# output and tests
print("Coefficients:\n", C)
print("TESTING:")
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    result = "[OK]" if np.allclose(_y, poly(_x)) else "[ERROR]"
    print(_x, " mapped to: ", poly(_x), " ; expected: ", _y, result)
```

This code calculates coefficients of the Lagrange interpolation polynomial, prints them, and tests that given x's are mapped into expected y's. You can test this code with [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb), so you don't have to install anything. Probably, you can translate it to JS.

Comment: I don't think it will be any of use because this require use of numpy which hide all the algorithms behind the API. So it don't tell you how this actually works. This is code is too much high level numpy to be of any use in other language than Python.

Comment: I need some time to think... Probably I can find a way to minimize numpy usage.

Comment: It seems, the only numpy function that is vital to coefficients calculation is determinant (numpy.linalg.det) -- I was able to remove all the rest (except numpy.allclose that is used for testing only).

Comment: Also, giving a numpy answer to a javascript question is not super useful. JS has no numpy equivalent.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , I agree, I just wanted to help by providing the algorithm, but when it came to implementation I understood that Python is the best I can do. Anyway, there is only 1 nympy function - det that calculates determinant. I'm sure there should be a certain JS library that can calculate determinants.

Comment: Right, but the way python arrays work (including things like `range`) is so different from how JS works that people only familiar with JS will have _no idea_ what's going on in this code, and would first need to learn Python list comprehension and slicing. At the very least, this needs more code comments and spaced out maths because `_x**i*(-1)**(i*len(x)) ` is too dense to intuit =)

Answer (score -1):

I want to share my way of solving this problem. Perhaps it has already been demonstrated in one of the above answers, but I have not looked at them. Wrote in c++

My idea is to represent a polynomial as an array of coefficients at unknown .i-th degrees. Maybe I spoke badly, but I'll give you an example. imagine 4x^2 + 3x^1 + 5x^0 as an array [53 4]. Then if we take another array and [ 1 2 4] and multiply them by the rule X[i+j] = A[i]*B[j]. then we can get the coefficients of the new polynomial, which was obtained as a result of multiplying the past ones. I want to explain why X[ i + j]. This comes out because we multiply numbers with the same base(x) and different degrees, in which case the degrees add up. However, it's worth noting that this only works with natural numbers.

In My program, the Polinom function is responsible for multiplying polynomials.

VectorSum is responsible for adding the coefficients of two polynomials.

VectorMult is responsible for multiplying all the coefficients of a polynomial by a certain number.

Let's now consider the lagranz function.We create an empty array filled with zeros, which in the outer loop will be filled with a part of the polynomial. In the inner loop, we find the value of the SubResult polynomial by multiplying it by the SubPolinom polynomial. SubPolinom represents a value at point X that is not equal to the current iteration of the loop,((X - Xj) | i != j).

SubResult represents the coefficients of the polynomial (X-X1)(X-X2)...(X-Xn), which will appear after opening the brackets.

Then we multiply the SubResult by a certain number, which will appear as a result Yi / ( (Xi - X0)...(Xi-X(j-1))(Xi -Xj) ), where i is not equal to j.
At the very end, we add up the SubResult with the previous iteration of the loop.

Thus we obtain the coefficients of the Langrange interpolation polynomial

```
    #include <iostream>;
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
vector<double> vectorSum(vector<double> A, vector<double> B) { // функция, складывающая элементы матриц при соответствующий коэф
    vector<double>result(A.size(), 0);
    if (A.size() > B.size() ){ //проверяем на одинаковость размерности матриц, если не сходятся, то увеличиваем меньшую, добавляя нули в конец
        B.resize(A.size(), 0);
    }
    else {
        A.resize(B.size(), 0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
    return result;
}
vector<double> vectorMult( vector<double> A, double C) { // Функци, которая умножает все элементы матрицы на определенный коэф
    vector<double>result(A.size(), 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = A[i] * C;
    }
    return result;
}
void showPolynom(vector<double> &F) { //функция, которая выводит многочлен в привычном виде
    string res;
    for (int i = 0; i < F.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            res += to_string(F[0]);
        }else if (i == 1) {
            if (F[i] == 1) {
                res+=  " + X";
            }
            else {
                res += " + " +to_string(F[i]) + "X";

            }
        }
        else {
            if (F[i] == 1) {
                res += " + X^" + to_string(i);
            }
            else {
                res += " + " + to_string(F[i]) + "X^" + to_string(i);
            }
        }
    }
    res += "\n";
    cout << res;
}
vector<double> Polinom(vector<double> &A, vector<double> &B) { // функция, которая умножает многочлен на многочлен( например (x-2)(x+2) = x^2 - 4)
    vector<double> result(A.size() + B.size() - 1, 0.0); // создаем массив, который будет размером, как максимальная степень одного плюс макс второго - 1
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++)
        {   // так как позиция элемента представляет собой степеь x, а значение элемента коэф при соответсвующем x, то при умножении одного на другого степени складываются, а значения перемножаются
        }   // Приведу пример: (x + 5) = (5x^0 + 1x^1) будет представлять массив [5, 1]. Возьмем другой массив [5, 1]. на выхлде функции у нас получится массив [25, 5 + 5, 1] = [25, 10, 1]
            // Если мы проведем умножение двух многочленов вручную, то получим (x+5)(x+5) = (x^2 + 5x +5x + 25) = (x^2+10x+25), что соответветсвует массиву [25,10,1]
            result[i + j] += A[i] * B[j]; 
    }
    return result;
}
vector<double>  lagranz(vector<double> X, vector<double> Y) { //сама функция, которая считает  многочлен лангранжа 
    int size = X.size();
    vector<double> result(size, 0); // вспомогательые переменные
    vector<double> subResult;
    vector<double> subPolinom(2, 1);
    double C;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        C = Y[i]; // коэф при Yi
        subResult = { 1 }; //единичные многочлен, представляющий собой 1 
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i != j) {
                C /= (X[i] - X[j]); // тут мы вычисляем знаменатель П(Xi - Xj) i!=j
                subPolinom[0] = -X[j];  // создаем ногочлен (X - Xj)
                subResult = Polinom(subResult, subPolinom); //перемножаем многочлены, чтобы получить коэф. П(X - Xj) i!=j
            }
        }
        subResult = vectorMult(subResult, C); // умножаем наш многочлен на константу
        result = vectorSum(result, subResult); // складываем полученные многочлены
    }
    return result; // возвращаем коэф многочлена лангранжа
}
int main() {
    vector<double> X = { -3, -1, 3, 5 };
    vector<double> Y = { 7, -1, 4, -6};
    vector<double> result = lagranz(X, Y); // передаем значения
    showPolynom(result); // выводим результат
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is always more useful if you provide explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is this an answer to a javascript question?